# Can't access files in a True Image backup

Tags: security, backup, restore, acronis-trueimage

I recently reinstalled my system from scratch (updated from windows 7 RC to the final version). Before that, I created a backup/image of the system drive using "Acronis True Image Home 2010".

Now I'd like to retrieve some files from that backup but it seems this is not possible for some directories. I can successfully mount the image as a drive (e.g. using drive letter M:) and can access most of the files and directories, except some directories such as `M:\Users\{username}\Documents`of my previous account.

E.g. when I try to access the directory `M:\Users\Martin` in the backup I get an access denied error (the system is in german, so I can't give the exact error message). I guess this is because that directory belonged to a different user than the one I'm using on the current system (even though both had the same name).

Is there any way to access the files in that directory without having to restore the full system from the backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to access the files when mounting the backup as a drive, but when I used the "normal" restore function of acronis true image I could get the files I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As Molly mentioned, you may need to take ownership of the directory and grant yourself full access.

It may also be the case that those directories are encrypted with EFS (encrypted file system), a feature of NTFS.  If this is the case, you will have to either restore the encryption keys to an account on your new installation, or restore the backup and copy the files to a separate drive (or you could also recreate the backup image, this time telling TrueImage to decrypt files before imaging--there's a checkbox to do this).

Comment: In addition to rob's answer: If the files are protected by EFS.  You will probably need to restore the system.  Also, if you forgot the password to that account, I believe resetting the password will clear their certificates and you would loose access to those files.  Windows has a Recovery Agent certificates what will allow you to decrypt the files.  You can add those certificates to your account.  I believe there are tutorials online on how to recover EFS protected files using the recovery agent.  Also, on your new system, if you use EFS, it is a good idea to back those certificates up.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm not using EFS, unless this is the default for Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to take ownership of the folder. for your convenience you may:

**[Add Take Ownership Option in Right Click Context Menu of Windows 7](http://www.blogsdna.com/2173/add-take-ownership-option-in-right-click-context-menu-of-windows-7.htm)**

[image]

Since your system language is German, you may want to edit the reg file and change "Take Ownership" to the German equivalent.

Comment: I couldn't find this option.

Comment: of course not, didn't you read the article? you'll have to import the Registry file provided there in order to have this option in your context menu. direct download link: http://www.blogsdna.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/takeownership.zip

Comment: It might be more helpful to include the instructions on how to take ownership without tinkering with the registry.

Answer (score 0):

When you restore files from Acronis on the last screen it asks if you want to keep the security settings, if you uncheck this box then you can access any of the files / folders in the .tib file.